# call ajax on Marketo submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, marketo

**My Requirement**

- In wordpress plugin I need to include a Marketo script
- On Submit of Marketo Form I need to do some calculation using Marketo Form elements
- Display the results on page

Please suggest a solution to implement this.

**What I have tried**

For this I am trying to use ajax on click of Marketo submit but it isn't working,
it stops abrubtly and doesn't even return to the ReturnURL specified in Marketo. The code I have tried:

```
 <script src="//xxxxx.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_1"></form>
<script>
MktoForms2.loadForm("//aqq-abc.marketo.com", "xxx-XXX-xxx", id1, function(form) {
    form.onSubmit(function(e) {e.preventDefault();

        var vals = form.vals();

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST", 
          url: "http://localhost:3422/wordpress/plugin/calculationFILE.php",
          data: {Value1:val["Email"],Value2: vals["Phone"]},
          success: function( data ) { alert(data); },
          error:  function( err ) {alert("Some thing went wrong! Please try again with your values.");}
        }); //ajax call end

        alert("OK after ajax"); //========>THIS IS NOT CALLED-but if ajax statement removed this alert fires. 
      });//OnSubmit end
});//loadForm End
```

- where I have all calculation to be placed in the file *calculationFILE.php*
- alert("OK after ajax"); //===>THIS IS NOT CALLED-but if ajax statement removed this alert fires.

**Edit**

I have included e.preventDefault() as now in the above code.I still not able to see ajax call executing.
Do I need to include jQuery to make this work?
What is that I am missing here.
Your suggestion for solution would of great help to move forward.

Comment: prevent the form submission using `e.preventDefault`

Comment: First try correctly [enqueueing the script](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/1103/enqueuing-scripts/3542/enqueuing-scripts-in-functions-php#t=201610250555007697672) and then inside, as mandalin suggested, prevent the default form action (submitting).

Comment: ok thanks madalin & dingo_d. I'll try this.

Comment: I have included e.preventDefault but still not able to make ajax call. Please help.I have enqueued script like the below:function. The alerts inside the js are working fine. Only the ajax call not getting executed.==============>>>>>>>jMy_enqueue_script() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jMy_js', plugins_url('js/marketo_jquery.js', __FILE__)  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jMy_enqueue_script' );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to include the jQuery lib to make the ajax call. After that it recognized the ajax call. The complete working snippet is

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//xxxxx.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_1"></form>
<script>
MktoForms2.loadForm("//aqq-abc.marketo.com", "xxx-XXX-xxx", id1, function(form) {
    form.onSubmit(function() {

        var vals = form.vals();

        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "http://localhost:3422/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/calM/new_generate.php",
                data: {Value1:vals.Email,Value2: vals.Phone},
        success: function( data ) {
                    alert(data);

        },
        error:  function( err ) {alert("Some thing went wrong! Please try again with your values.");}
        });

      });
});
```